# Java replaceAll regex With Similar Result

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

Alright folks, my brain is fried. I'm trying to fix up some EMLs with bad boundaries by replacing the incorrect

```
--Boundary_([ArbitraryName])
```

lines with more proper

```
--Boundary_([ArbitraryName])--
```

lines, while leaving already correct

```
--Boundary_([ThisOneWasFine])--
```

lines alone. I've got the whole message in-memory as a String (yes, it's ugly, but JavaMail dies if it tries to parse these), and I'm trying to do a replaceAll on it. Here's the closest I can get.

```
//Identifie bondary lines that do not end in --
String regex = "^--Boundary_\\([^\\)]*\\)$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex,
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(targetString);
//Store all of our unique results.
HashSet<String> boundaries = new HashSet<String>();
while (matcher.find())
    boundaries.add(s);
//Add "--" at the end of the Strings we found.
for (String boundary : boundaries)
    targetString = targetString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(boundary),
        boundary + "--");
```

This has the obvious problem of replacing all of the valid

```
--Boundary_([WasValid])--
```

lines with

```
--Boundary_([WasValid])----
```

However, this is the only setup I've gotten to even perform the replacement. If I try changing Pattern.quote(boundary) to Pattern.quote(boundary) + "$", nothing is replaced. If I try just using matcher.replaceAll("$0--") instead of the two loops, nothing is replaced. What's an elegant way to achieve my aim and why does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to iterate through the matches with `find()`; that's part of what `replaceAll()` does.

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?im)^--Boundary_\\([^\\)]*\\)$", "$0--");
```

The `$0` in the replacement string is a placeholder whatever the regex matched in this iteration.

The `(?im)` at the beginning of the regex turns on CASE_INSENSITIVE and MULTILINE modes.

Comment: Thanks; that did the trick even though my previous attempts at $0 didn't. Except now I'm sorely scratching my head as I'm not sure how I'd bungled it, but I'll chalk that one up to extreme fatigue and call this one done. Accepting this one as the most elegant and well explained (but thanks, everyone else).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
String regex = "^--Boundary_\\([^\\)]*\\)(--)?$";
```

then see if the string ends with `--` and replace only ones that don't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the strings are on there own line this works: 
**`"(?im)^--Boundary_\\([^)]*\\)$"`**

Example script:

```
String str = "--Boundary_([ArbitraryName])\n--Boundary_([ArbitraryName])--\n--Boundary_([ArbitraryName])\n--Boundary_([ArbitraryName])--\n";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?im)^--Boundary_\\([^)]*\\)$", "$0--"));
```

Edit: changed from JavaScript to Java, must have read too fast.(Thanks for pointing it out)

Comment: You're suggesting he use the JavaScript scripting engine?